# How to convert latex/MathML expression into English language

Tags: java, latex, mathml

I am looking for an API preferably in JAVA which can convert a MathML/ Latex expression into the English language. [WIRIS](http://www.wiris.com/editor/docs/servicesapis) is one option but I am looking for an open source implementation.

Input

**MathML expression**

```
MathML -input:"<math><mfrac><mn>1</mn><mn>4</mn></mfrac></math>
```

**Latex expression**

```
\frac14
```

Expected output:

```
- 1 fourth
```

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)